# How I get the value of a variable using the lag position that comes from another variable?

Tags: r, loops, indexing, conditional-statements, lag

I am trying to get the values of a variable (B) that cames from the lag position given by other variable (A).

The variables are something like this:

```
#    A  B
# 1: 1 10
# 2: 1 20
# 3: 1 30
# 4: 1 40
# 5: 2 50
```

I want the output (C) to be like this, the first value woud be zero and the condition start in the second row:

```
#    A  B C
# 1: 1 10 0
# 2: 1 20 10
# 3: 1 30 20
# 4: 2 40 20
# 5: 2 50 30
```

I have done it with loops but because it´s a large amount of information is a lot of time to wait. I hope someone could give me an idea.

Comment: why do you have repeated 20? ie row 4 has 20

Comment: Because `A` gives the amount of lag, and `A` is 2 in row 4.

Comment: Because column A tells me that I have to get the value 2 places above 40 (Column B). I don't know if I'm being clear.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, `A` changes from your example input to your example output. In row 4, `A` is 1 in your first code block, but `A` is 2 in your second code block.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(
    C = c(0, B[(2:n()) - A[-1]])
  )
#    A  B  C
# 1: 1 10  0
# 2: 1 20 10
# 3: 1 30 20
# 4: 2 40 20
# 5: 2 50 30
```

It translates directly to `data.table` (with your colons in row names, I thought you might be using that package)

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(x)
dt[, C := c(0, B[(2:.N) - A[-1]])]
dt
#    A  B  C
# 1: 1 10  0
# 2: 1 20 10
# 3: 1 30 20
# 4: 2 40 20
# 5: 2 50 30
```

---

Using this data:

```
x = read.table(text ='   A  B
1: 1 10
2: 1 20
3: 1 30
4: 2 40
5: 2 50', header = T)
```